# Captcha in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Any captcha plugin for django admin?

I want to add this functionality at admin login.

Comment: I dont know if someone already has done any plugin for this purpose. You could do your own login view, just remember that the "backend" needs an authenticated user which inherits the roles admin and editor (hope these are the right terms for the roles.)

Comment: Why at admin login? What purpose is that serving? If you're going to use a captcha somewhere, you would want it on account creation.

Comment: I mean login in django administration tool, usually with url http://host/admin/

Comment: I think it can be a good way to prevent brute force attack. I will use the same thing but if you guys have any other idea I can learn :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can override [AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects) class and set your login_form and login_template. But in this case you need to register all your models via your custom AdminSite object.

Answer (score 2):

An idea could be to force the /admin to use another login view (http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2127/). I think youll have to import the login_required decorator in that snippet.

Now you can provide your own [login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests) which implements i.e. recaptcha.
You can easily integrate it into your custom login form (http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html).
In your authentication view youll just have to check the returning value from the recaptcha api (it returns "true" or "false" as first part of the string, so split it) like this:

```
import urllib, urllib2
def recaptcha(request, postdata):
        rc_challenge = postdata.get('recaptcha_challenge_field','')
        rc_user_input = postdata.get('recaptcha_response_field', '').encode('utf-8')
        url = 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify'
        values = {'privatekey' : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'remoteip': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'challenge' : rc_challenge, 'response' : rc_user_input,}
        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        result = response.read().split()[0]
        response.close()
        return result
```

In your view check the following POST data:

```
def login_view(request, template_name="login.html"):   
if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        captcha = recaptcha(request, postdata)
        form = LoginUserForm(request, postdata)
        if captcha == "false":
            return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        if form.is_valid():
        # do authentication here
else:
# just display the login_form on GET request
```

You can use the variable "captcha" to render an error message in your template, if the user input returned false on the captcha. Youll also have to define your own LoginUserForm to use in a separate custom HTML template.

This is just a littel hacky concept from my head, I think, a more elegant way could be to write a custom captcha widget.

Hope these thoughts may lead to a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Simple Captcha](http://code.google.com/p/django-simple-captcha/)?

Comment: Thanks for link. How it helps me in django admin?

Comment: You could use this to implement the custom feature by yourself since it is not yet available, as far as I know. Guaranteed it's going to be a lot of work.